# Cassandra IS NOT NULL Unsupported restriction

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

The materialized view is not populated when I run it. I think it's because the SQL query generates errors.

```
select * from table where id is not null

InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported restriction: id IS NOT NULL"
```

Previously this SQL query was that let me place is not null. I think that when I do an update of the system this fails me.

Comment: Yes, that works in SQL.  But CQL does not allow that.

Comment: materialized view needs IS NOT NULL 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateMaterializedView.html

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your MV definition?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) 
Cassandra  3.11.3

Answer (score 2):

So cassandra's where clause support `=`, `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=`.  There is no support for `not null` or `!=` null.  It is worth noting the only time `IS NOT NULL` exists is within the materialized view.  This is because you cannot have a null in your primary key and in this case you're coercing variables that might be otherwise unset INTO a primary key.  Additionally you do need to include all of the primary key from the base table in your materialized view.

#### Example Materialized View

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test_keyspace
WITH REPLICATION = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};

CREATE TABLE myTable(
  id int, 
  col1 varchar, 
  col2 varchar, 
PRIMARY KEY(id, col1)) ;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_view AS 
  SELECT col2, col1, id FROM myTable 
  WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL AND col1 IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(col2, id, col1);
```

It should be noted materialized views come with some performance implications and you may be better off rolling your own.

Comment: Yes i know.
When I create the materialized view, it doesn't fill. It's empty
It's been happening to me for a few days.

Comment: I think that the problem is the base table. Because the base table has 1TB and materialized view crash.

Comment: Is there anything in the table?  Do the logs say anything?  what does `SELECT * FROM system.built_views;` produce?  What does `SELECT * FROM system.views_builds_in_progress;` produce?

I've built larger materialized views, but typically my issue was that it starved the cluster for resources and never caught up.